# Express dynamically display associated page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a simple express app.

The problem i have now is when any of the navigation link (Home, Home1, Home2) is clicked, it's returning an error but if i type  http://localhost:8001/home1 -> it will display home1.html.

so, what i wanted is, by the time user click one of the navigation link, it should take them to the appropriate page.

Any help, i will highly appreciate.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use('/temp', express.static(__dirname + '/temp'));

app.get('/home', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/temp/home.html')
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGEjl.png)

Comment: Please show the HTML for the navigation links.  Please explain where in your server file system the matching files `Home1` and `Home2` are located.  If `http://localhost:8001/home1` works, but clicking on the `home1` link does not work, then apparently that link is generating the wrong URL.  Please show us the HTML for that link.

Comment: all my files are in a folder called "temp" -> which has all my html files. Also, they all have this path ```<a class="nav-link" href="./home.html">Home</a>```

Comment: I asked for the link for Home1, the one that you say does not work.  Also, don't use `./` in HTML links.  Start them with a `/`.

Comment: it actually worked, i had them pointing to the wrong dir and wrong format. Thanks @jfriend00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `./` in your HTML links.  Change your links in the HTML to start with `/` instead so that the links do not depend upon the path of the current page's URL.